# Why do I have an extra dot in my owl carousel navigation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have a couple of problems with my owl carousel. One being that it isn't responsive at the moment, but that is another issue! At the moment I keep getting 3 dots, however there should only be 2. I want to have 2 items in the middle of the page (I have the max-width of the .owl-carousel set to 500px). Here is my markup:

```
<div id="owl-cd" class="owl-carousel">
<div class="item"><img src=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

Here is my custom CSS:

```
#owl-cd .item img{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#owl-cd .item {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
color: #686974;
border: 0;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

And my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-cd").owlCarousel({
  items: 2,
  dots: true,
  margin: 20,
  autoWidth:true,
  center:false,
  }
  );
});
```

Apologies if I haven't included everything required, I am very new to developing. Just trying out some things but not sure why I am getting 3 dots instead of 2 and why it is not responsive at the moment!

Comment: I also have changed something else in the owl css: .owl-carousel .owl-item {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
max-width: 240px;

Comment: It looks like the slider isn't completely smart. Try adding the attribute `itemsMobile: [10000,2]` to your plugin initialization. That will tell it to set 2 items whenever the screen is smaller than 10000.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that but it doesn't seem to have done anything..?

Comment: Well, the dots are the number of items divided by how many show up on the page... so if you have 2 per page, and 6 items, it will show 3 dots.

Comment: I have 2 per page and only 3 items. When I click the third dot it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: It seems to work fine in a fiddle I set up. http://jsfiddle.net/n3mcyo7c/

Comment: ah yes... hmm I'm truly stumped then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by separating the owl-carousel class and putting it inside a separate owl-cd div id. So:

```
<div id="owl-cd">
<div class="owl-carousel">
<div class="item"><img src=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src=""></div>
<div class="item"><img src=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I also removed the max-width from .owl-carousel in my CSS and applied it to #owl-cd.

Answer (score 0):

$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
rewind: true
})